# vite does not rewrite proxy path of axios instance / vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api

I`m working on my first project with the composition api and vite.
I am trying to avoid a CORS problem and need to proxy my requests.

*vite.config.js*

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://dest.com/api',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I am using vue-axios for my requests.

*main.js*

```
// Axios
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

const app = createApp(App);

// Init
app.use(createPinia());
app.use(router);
app.use(PrimeVue);
app.use(VueAxios, axios);

app.mount('#app');
```

This is working fine so far. But when I make requests from a custom axios instance like this one

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const SMCCLIENT = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://dest.com`,
  auth: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  },
  header: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
});
```

The proxy does not handle the requests.

*Test.vue*

```
async function getElements() {
  const test = await SMCCLIENT.get('/api/test/', {
  });
  console.log(test);
}
```

**Results in CORS Error**

*Test.vue*

```
async function getElements() {
  const test = await axios.get('/api/test/', {
  });
  console.log(test);
}
```

**Works fine**
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't expect that requests to https://dest.com will be intercepted by magic. The only way a proxy can work is that requests are made to local /api/ . 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' doesn't make sense in a browser

Comment: Thanks your comment. With default instance of axios, the rewrite is working. (Last Code Block). But is is not working with a custom instance of axios.

Comment: It will work with any instance, but you shouldn't use remote server as baseURL